# VS 2013 isn't able to attach 64bit debugger

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I've a very annoying problem with visual studio 2012/2013, on both version it's not able to attach the debugger for a x64 application. The debugging for application configured with AnyCpu or x86 is working without problems. I can't simply switch a part of my programs to x86 applications, because I'm develop azure webroles which have to be x64 application.

How it looks when I start to debug:

After a while of waiting a window pops up which show:

[image: Operation taking longer than expected]

When I click Terminate, sometimes the same window pops up again.
After I clicked Terminate again, it shows this window:

[image]

Or this instead, when I'm trying to debug a azure webrole hoste in the azure emulator:

[image]

I'm frustraited now and I hope you guys can help me.

The list of things I've tried:

- Reinstalled VS 2012/2013 (both of them)
- Checked firewall rules, they're ok.
- Checked for 3rd party network software, <strike>none found</strike>  NIC's driver (See Edit)
- Reinstalled azure tools
- Reinstalled IIS 7.5 (in Programs and Features)
- Done a lot of research in web but found nothing that worked.

At last the Windows7 installation is from two days ago (01.13.2014).

EDIT: After hours of research, testing, tons of reoots and reinstallations, I found the cause. It's the netowrk card driver. I've a Bogfoot Network Killer Ethernet Controller which needs a special "3rd party" driver. It's working when I uninstall the driver. I'll try to install a normal nic (Intel/Realtek, if I find one) tomorrow and post the result here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found the solution and I think it's less painful as it sounds at the begining.

Simply removed the driver of my Bigfoot Network Killer onboard ethernet card (MB: G1.Sniper). Then installed a Intel Pro/1000 and it worked like a charm. I don't know if there is a solution which you don't have to add/replace hardware.

But now it works!